# flask web server How to access page using local domain instead of ip

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am running a flask app. For some reason I can't access the app on other computers on the network using myapp.local or (the_device_real_name.load) unless I do it on the computer the app is running on. I can access it on other computers on the network if I use the ip address. I also opened the host file in /etc/hosts and added the name I wanted there.  How can I fix this issue.

in flask I have:
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'myapp.local' 
I also have host='0.0.0.0'

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There are myriad reasons why this could be happening. If you think you've accounted for everything and it's still not working, trying flushing the DNS on the client computer.

Comment: Is the port that flask is running on(usually 5000) accepting traffic from the network?

Comment: I have flask app running on port 80. I tried a DNS flush. Note if I run appach web server I can access webpages on any local computer with appname.local but if I just run with flask it does not give me that option

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your Flask configuration.

and to be noted, this comment is from `flask/helpers.py line 241`

```
Configuration values ``APPLICATION_ROOT`` and ``SERVER_NAME`` are only used when
generating URLs outside of a request context.
```

They have nothing to do with matching your app with a hostname.

in order for the other computers on your local network to access your app,
you either need to append `hosts` file on these computers with the mapping of

```
myapp.local    <<<YOUR_DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>>>
```

or if there is a DNS server in your local network, you need to update the records to map your machine IP address to `myapp.local`